# Gridview and Databases in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two databases.  A Product Database and a Product Database.  I am passing information from various ways.  The OrderID which is the primary key of the Order Table to increment.  I have it set to increment, but I am missing something.  Everything is working as long as I hard code an OrderID into it.  Can anyone tell me what I should be putting after SqlDataSource.InsertParameters["OrderID"].DefaultValue= 
to make it work?

```
GridViewRow gr1 = GridView1.SelectedRow;

    Label lblProdID = gr1.FindControl("Label1") as Label;

    SqlDataSource3.InsertParameters["OrderDate"].DefaultValue = "11/06/2017";
    SqlDataSource3.InsertParameters["CustID"].DefaultValue = TextBox2.Text;
    SqlDataSource3.InsertParameters["OrderID"].DefaultValue = "12346";
    SqlDataSource3.InsertParameters["ProdID"].DefaultValue = lblProdID.Text;
    SqlDataSource3.InsertParameters["OrderQty"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)gr1.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
    SqlDataSource3.Insert();
```

Comment: 1. This is presumably test code because if you want to create new records then you would not use Default values

2. Order ID  should be a unique value so most times you would let your DataBase handle that by setting that field to be some AUTOINCREMENT ETC.

Comment: I have it incrementing by 1, but that is not helping.  If I eliminate that line of code, it gives me a null exception.  I need to put something after SqlDataSource.InsertParameters["OrderID"].DefaultValue= to make it work.......I think

Comment: how is your sqlDataSource3 INSERT COMMAND Defined ?

Comment: The OrderID column should be an `identity` column. If you are able to insert a value into that column then it is not identity (unless you have turned identity insert on which is doubtful). So I suggest you re-visit your table definition.

Comment: InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [ORDER] ([OrderID], [CustID], [ProdID], [OrderDate], [OrderQty]) VALUES (*OrderID, *CustID, *ProdID, *OrderDate, *OrderQty)"         I put an * where there should be an @ because stacked thought I was typing at people

Comment: there is your answer: You don't need to insert an OrderID so take it out of your SQL statement

Comment: Just to clarify: When I take out OrderID, because it's the primary key, I can no longer generate insert, update, and delete statements.  I need to be able to do that.

Comment: @Bob, when you say " generate insert " I assume you mean code that gets generated by VS. You can/have to modify that code as needed. You need to take it out of both the Insert command and input Parameters. If your Table has it defined as Identity, Auto Increment it WILL NOT accept it as a input.